# ImageIO.read(FileInputStream) returns null when reading a very large image

Tags: java, java-2d

I need to read an image, resize it and then save it.
However, when reading a very large image, `ImageIO#read()` returns null.

```
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(imagePath);     
image = ImageIO.read(f);
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Post your entire stack trace here, and let's see the root cause of the exception. Just a suggestion: avoid a chaining call like `request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath(imageUrl)` for exactly the reason that you're experiencing now. Break it up into smaller calls so you can narrow the source of your issues better

Comment: [ImageIO#read(InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) returns `null` if no registered reader was able to able to decode the image data from the inputstream. Are yousure youwas able to read smaller images of the same format as the large one?

Answer (score 1):

Image I/O has built-in support for GIF, PNG, JPEG, BMP, and WBMP only. Are you trying to load any other type of image than these. See [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for details.

You may check the list of registered readers using `ImageIO.getReaderFormatNames()`. For me it lists `[BMP, bmp, jpg, JPG, wbmp, jpeg, png, JPEG, PNG, WBMP, GIF, gif]`